# am having this error trying to run my django project runserver is not working

Tags: django

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\TECH STUDIO FILES\Ecommerce\ec\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\TECH STUDIO FILES\Ecommerce\ec\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    commands = get_commands()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 107, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 50, in _setup  
    self._configure_logging()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 72, in _configure_logging
    from django.utils.log import DEFAULT_LOGGING
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\log.py", line 7, in <module>     
    from django.views.debug import ExceptionReporter, get_exception_reporter_filter
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 12, in <module>  
    from django.template import Template, Context, TemplateDoesNotExist
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from django.template.base import (ALLOWED_VARIABLE_CHARS, BLOCK_TAG_END,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 19, in <module>
    from django.utils.html import escape
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\html.py", line 14, in <module>   
    from .html_parser import HTMLParser
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\html_parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    HTMLParseError = _html_parser.HTMLParseError
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'html.parser' has no attribute 'HTMLParseError'. Did you mean: 'HTMLParser'?
```

every thing but the server fails to run

Answer (score 1):

this has changed from django2.0 to django2.1:

django/utils/html.py

```
from .html_parser import HTMLParseError, HTMLParser    <=2.0
from html.parser import HTMLParser                     >=2.1
```

most certainly you are mixing and older version of django <=2.0 with a more recent python version (3.11) that does not fit

from django 2.1 release notes:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/releases/2.1/
:

*Django 2.1 supports Python 3.5, 3.6, and 3.7. Django 2.0 is the last version to support Python 3.4. We highly recommend and only officially support the latest release of each series.*